# Override router and add parameter to specific routes (before path/url used)

Tags: symfony, routes

I would use a easy management routing system.

For example NOW i have this routes.

```
_welcome                    ANY      ANY    ANY  /
acmedemo_example_index      ANY      ANY    ANY  /acme/demos
acmedemo_example_edit       ANY      ANY    ANY  /acme/edit/{id}
acmedemo_example_delete     ANY      ANY    ANY  /acme/delete/{id}
acmeapi_backup_get          GET      ANY    ANY  /api/acme
acmeapi_backup_edit         POST     ANY    ANY  /api/acme
```

Now I would add the current user id to each route, because if a user send me or another supporter/administrator a link, we would see what the user see.
You understand?

I would have this now.

```
_welcome                    ANY      ANY    ANY  /
acmedemo_example_index      ANY      ANY    ANY  /{user}/acme/demos
acmedemo_example_edit       ANY      ANY    ANY  /{user}/acme/edit/{id}
acmedemo_example_delete     ANY      ANY    ANY  /{user}/acme/delete/{id}
acmeapi_backup_get          GET      ANY    ANY  /api/acme
acmeapi_backup_edit         POST     ANY    ANY  /api/acme
```

And now the "problem"... I want to add the "user" parameter to each route automatically if the route name matches `preg_match('/^acmedemo_/i')`.

For example (index.html.twig):

```
<a href="{{ path('acmedemo_example_index') }}">Show demos</a>
```

Or

```
<a href="{{ path('acmedemo_example_edit', {id: entity.id}) }}">Edit demo</a>
```

I **NOT** want to use `{{ path('acmedemo_example_edit', {id: entity.id, user: app.user.id}) }}`**!**

And the "user" parameter requires "\d+".

I would like to override the "generate" function on the router, for example.
Then I could check if `$router->getUrl()` matches the `^acmedemo_` and then I could add the `user` parameter :)

Thanks!

Comment: I fail to see the question in this question (except from "You understand?" which isn't a fit for SO :P)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Soooo new day for me **:D**

I overrided the router and the UrlGenerator.

@***Chausser***: I fixed your problem 1 with an easy:

```
acme_demo_example:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /{user}
```

Now I have routes like this.

```
_welcome                    ANY      ANY    ANY  /
acmedemo_example_index      ANY      ANY    ANY  /{user}/acme/demos
acmedemo_example_edit       ANY      ANY    ANY  /{user}/acme/edit/{id}
acmedemo_example_delete     ANY      ANY    ANY  /{user}/acme/delete/{id}
acmeapi_examples_get        GET      ANY    ANY  /api/acme
acmeapi_examples_edit       POST     ANY    ANY  /api/acme
```

**Problem 1 solved!**

Now problem 2, because I want no extra route function or something else.
I want to use `<a href="{{ path('acmedemo_example_index') }}">Show demos</a>` and `<a href="{{ path('acmedemo_example_edit', {id: entity.id}) }}">Edit demo</a>`.

But if I would use that I would get errors.
Also lets do this.

The problem I had with this service is that I have no container >.<

*services.yml*

```
parameters:
    router.class: Acme\DemoBundle\Routing\Router
    router.options.generator_base_class: Acme\DemoBundle\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator
```

*Acme\DemoBundle\Routing\Router*

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router as BaseRouter;
class Router extends BaseRouter implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, $resource, array $options = array(), RequestContext $context = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($container, $resource, $options, $context);
        $this->setContainer($container);
    }

    public function getGenerator()
    {
        $generator = parent::getGenerator();
        $generator->setContainer($this->container);
        return $generator;
    }

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }
}
```

*Acme\DemoBundle\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator*

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator as BaseUrlGenerator;
class UrlGenerator extends BaseUrlGenerator implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    private $container;

    protected function doGenerate($variables, $defaults, $requirements, $tokens, $parameters, $name, $referenceType, $hostTokens)
    {
        /** Set the default user parameter for the routes which haven't a user parameter */
        if(preg_match('/^acmedemo_/i', $name) && in_array('user', $variables) && !array_key_exists('user', $parameters))
        {
            $parameters['user'] = $this->getUser()->getId();
        }

        return parent::doGenerate($variables, $defaults, $requirements, $tokens, $parameters, $name, $referenceType, $hostTokens);
    }

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    /**
     * @see \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface::getUser()
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        if (!$this->container->has('security.context')) {
            throw new \LogicException('The SecurityBundle is not registered in your application.');
        }

        if (null === $token = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()) {
            return null;
        }

        if (!is_object($user = $token->getUser())) {
            return null;
        }

        return $user;
    }
}
```

**Problem 2 solved!**

*(Codes writed by me on Symfony**2.3**)*

Thanks for your help. But this is better I think ***=)***

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22510569/override-router-and-add-parameter-to-specific-routes-before-path-url-used/31859779#answer-31859779) for a much cleaner and non intrusive solution using Request listener and router context :)

Answer (score 6):

Actually there is a much simpler way to do that using `RequestContext::setParameter()` method. This context is available through the router via `Router::getContext()` method.

Use a [kernel listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html) on [incoming requests](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-request) to initialize this context or, when outside of a request scope (command for example), directly by calling the method on the router service.

```
$router->getContext()->setParameter('user', $user->getId());

// where $router is the @router service.
```

---

Example of request listener:

```
namespace AppBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RequestContextAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

/**
 * Add user param to router context on new request.
 */
class UserAwareRouterContextSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @var TokenStorageInterface
     */
    private $tokenStorage;

    /**
     * @var RequestContextAwareInterface
     */
    private $router;

    /**
     * @param TokenStorageInterface        $tokenStorage
     * @param RequestContextAwareInterface $router
     */
    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage, RequestContextAwareInterface $router)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [KernelEvents::REQUEST => 'onRequest'];
    }

    /**
     * @param GetResponseEvent $event
     */
    public function onRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
            return;
        }

        if ($token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()) {
            $user = $token->getUser();
            if ($user instanceof MyUserClass) { // use your own class here :)
                $this->router->getContext()->setParameter('user', $user->getId());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Service configuration:

```
services:
    app.listener.user_aware_router_context:
        class: AppBundle\Listener\UserAwareRouterContextSubscriber
        arguments:
            - '@security.token_storage'
            - '@router'
        tags:
            - {name: kernel.event_subscriber}
```

Comment: I don't know if this answers the question, but this post actually saved my life, I do exactly need this ! In my use case, a site might be browsed via an IFrame, case in which all generated URL context must be changed to be able to dynamically change the page layout. Thank you sir !

Comment: @Pierre thank you :) I've updated the answer with an example of implementation.

Answer (score 1):

With this you have 2 main problems:

**PROBLEM 1**

The way you have your urls setup you will need to have 2 routes. http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#required-and-optional-placeholders

> Of course, you can have more than one optional placeholder (e.g. /blog/{slug}/{page}), but everything after an optional placeholder must be optional. For example, /{page}/blog is a valid path, but page will always be required (i.e. simply /blog will not match this route).

Meaning even if you do override how the route is generated when the request comes in for `/acme/demos` it will not match `acmedemo_example_index` if it is expecting `/{user}/acme/demos` even if `{user}` is optional.

For this you have 2 optional fixes:

**FIX 1**

Have 2 routes, one to match with the user and one to match with out. both pointing to the same controller action:

```
acmedemo_example_index            ANY      ANY    ANY  /acme/demos
acmedemo_example_index_with_user  ANY      ANY    ANY  /{user}/acme/demos
```

**FIX 2**

Move your optional `{user}` parameter to the end of the url:

```
acmedemo_example_index            ANY      ANY    ANY  /acme/demos/{user}
```

**PROBLEM 2**

You will need a way to generate the route. For this personally i would create a Twig Function that will basically do what `path()` does but will append the user.

Take a look at the documentation on how to write a twig extension: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

When registering the extension you will need to pass in some additional services so that you can generate the routes and so you can get the current user.

```
# src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    acme.twig.acme_extension:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Twig\AcmeExtension
        arguments: ["@security.context","@router"]
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Then in the extension you will need to use a contructor:

```
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/Twig/AcmeExtension.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Twig;

class AcmeExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    protected $user;
    protected $router;

    public function __construct($security,$router)
    {
        $this->user = $security->getToken()->getUser();
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /* Declare your function */

    public function acmePath($route,$params,$requirements)
    {
        if(strpos($route,'acmedemo_')===false){
            return $this->router->generate($route,$params,$requirements);
        }
        /** IF YOU USE FIX 1 **/
        array_merge($params,array('user'=>$this->user));
        $newRoute = $route.'_with_user';
        return $this->router->generate($newRoute ,$params,$requirements);

        /** IF YOU USE FIX 2 **/
        array_merge($params,array('user'=>$this->user));
        return $this->router->generate($route,$params,$requirements);
    }
}
```

Then in your twig files use `acmePath()` rather than `path`:

```
<a href="{{ acmePath('acmedemo_example_index') }}">Show demos</a>
```

instead of:

```
<a href="{{ path('acmedemo_example_index') }}">Show demos</a>
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22510569/override-router-and-add-parameter-to-specific-routes-before-path-url-used/31859779#answer-31859779) for a much cleaner and non intrusive solution using Request listener and router context :)