# Symfony2 workaround when devices have cookies disabled

Tags: php, symfony, session, cookies

For a project I am required to have a persistent session for a visitor.
A couple of years ago I faced the issue with an Apple update temporary rendering all iPhones unable to set PHPSESSID cookies.

I created a fall back method which checked for the SESSION ID in the URL and use that to persist the session between requests. I am aware of the fact this can be enabled in php.ini using the `session.use_trans_sid`.

Point is I do not want this to happen always. When possible I prefer the cookie method. 
Is there a way within Symfony to add this logic to the route methods adding the session identifier?

Can anyone help me to explain where to extend the twig "path" method to add the logic to optionally append the session id to all URL's generated by that method.

**UPDATE**

Let me post an update on my progress and perhaps someone can help me. I managed to find how to extend the UrlGenerator with my own code by replacing the generator_base_class in a parameter.

Now I have the following issue.
I wish to use a session to do some logic. I however can not reach this core component as a service. I already tried makign a compilerPass for both the UrlGenerator and an extended Router class to be able to make a dependency injection in one of these classes.

However until now it sadly failed.
What would be the best partice to get the Session component within the UrlGenerator class?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create my solution thanks to this post: 
[Override router and add parameter to specific routes (before path/url used)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22510569/override-router-and-add-parameter-to-specific-routes-before-path-url-used/22527873#22527873)

In the end this is the code I came up with.

```
In my service.xml

<parameters>
    <parameter key="router.class">Acme\CoreBundle\Component\Routing\Router</parameter>
    <parameter key="router.options.generator_base_class">Acme\CoreBundle\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator</parameter>
</parameters>
```

Extending Symfony's core router to make in ContainerAware and force that container to the UrlGenerator.

```
namespace Acme\CoreBundle\Component\Routing;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router as BaseRouter;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RequestContext;

class Router extends BaseRouter implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, $resource, array $options = array(), RequestContext $context = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($container, $resource, $options, $context);
        $this->setContainer($container);
    }

    public function getGenerator()
    {
        $generator = parent::getGenerator();
        $generator->setContainer($this->container);
        return $generator;
    }

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }
}
```

Extending the UrlGenerator class.

```
namespace Acme\CoreBundle\Component\Routing\Generator;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator as BaseUrlGenerator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * UrlGenerator generates URL based on a set of routes, this class extends the basics from Symfony.
 */
class UrlGenerator extends BaseUrlGenerator implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    private $container;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    protected function doGenerate($variables, $defaults, $requirements, $tokens, $parameters, $name, $referenceType, $hostTokens, array $requiredSchemes = array())
    {
        /** @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session $session */
        $session = $this->container->get('session');
        if (true !== $session->get('acceptCookies')) {
            $parameters[$session->getName()] = $session->getId();
        }

        return parent::doGenerate($variables, $defaults, $requirements, $tokens, $parameters, $name, $referenceType, $hostTokens, $requiredSchemes);
    }
}
```

In the end this results in the session name and id being appended to the generated URL when the session value acceptCookies is not equal to true.